# Unable to trigger a selection event in bokeh

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

Can someone please tell me how to capture the option that is selected in the 'select' widget.
I tried the following and expected that when I change the selection in drop down menu, it should print the newly selected option.  But it's not happening.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

output_notebook()
states=['VA','MD','SC']

select = Select(title="Select State:", value="VA", options=states)

show(vform(select))

def call(attr,old,new):
    print new

select.on_change('value',select,call)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `on_change` incorrectly. It takes: the name of the property to respond to, and the callback. You don't need to pass the object, because `on_change` is already a method on the object. You want:

```
select.on_change('value', call)
```

Also, I will suggest that is unequivocably a good idea and almost always more efficient to try to and find a working example to start from, and then experiment with modifying that to suit your needs. The authors of the library have worked hard to add many examples to the GitHub repo so that users can learn from them. Several of them show working `Select` widgets. Here is one in particular:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stocks/main.py

As an aside, I'm actually surprised the `on_change` call doesn't fall over with an error immediately, the way you have it. Please consider contributing by making a GitHub issue to suggest better validation.

Comment: I tried using 'select.on_change('value',call)' as well.  However, the 'call' function (that was defined earlier) is not being triggered.  I am not getting any error but the event is also not being raised.  Do we need to setup anything on our machine to get these interactions (like bokeh server)

Comment: It's always a good idea to give a as many relevant details as possible, including how you are actually trying to run things. In this case I assumed you were using the Bokeh server, and knowing that you were not from the start would have saved time. Yes, you will need to run `bokeh serve myapp.py` to be able to use `on_change` callbacks. There's lots of documentation about running a Bokeh serve: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html